# reducer for Flux pattern in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, flux

I try to use flux pattern for making state management system in vanilla js.
in the course of design, I think 1 state need 1 reducer. but then many reducer is needed.
Is it right idea? 1 state is needed 1 reducer to controll state?

If this idea is right, reducers are combined to rootreducer.

Answer (score 0):

Reducer is a pure function which accepts previous state (any arbitrary object) and returns a new one (another arbitrary object) based on dispatched action.

I see no obstacles to reuse reducer function in more than one place if state and result looks the same as in another store. Take into consideration that you shouldn’t make two stores for the same data.

When it comes to not using reducer at all - so why use flux pattern at all? The main concept of flux is to dispatch action and then manipulate store based on this action using reducers. If you don't have any reducer then you wouldn't have any action. So this kind of store could be easily replaced by simple shared const variable with values.

So basically - Many reducers can control one state, like one reducer can remove value from state with provided ID and another one can add a value to this state. There's no problem with that. But you cannot make one reducer to control many states simontaneously.

Comment: thanks for answer

so, i understand if i have many states, many reducer is needed. thank you